# An infinite number of solutions available to the sparse representation problem

Tags: matrices, computer-science, normed-spaces

I would like to analyze the following problem (different cases leads to which solutions to the problem and such):

$$||y-Dx||_2 \leq \epsilon$$

(an overcomplete dictionary matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times K}$that contains $K$ prototype signal-atoms for columns, $\{d_j\}^K_{j=1}$ , a signal $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$can be represented as a sparse linear combination of these atoms)

[The paper I am reading](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~michalo/papers/IEEESubmission4.pdf), says:

> if $n < K$ and $D$ is full rank matrix, an infinite number of solutions are available for the problem, hence constraints on the solution must be set.

I need to know the reason behind this(that on the above conditions, there will be an infinite number of solutions), please shed some light on the problem.

I am a computer science graduate, so please explain in not-very complicated facts and theorms so that I can follow your reasoning, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n x K}$, it is a linear mapping from a $K$ dimensional space to an $n$ dimensional space. But , we are given that $K>n$. So, in a sense we are mapping a "bigger" space to a "smaller" space and we are looking for a solution to $Dx=y$.i.e., given $y$ in the "smaller" space find $x$ in the bigger space such that $Dx=y$. There could be many such $x$'s satisfying this equation. Therefore we need more constraints to get a unique solution.

Comment: To make this clear. You are going from $K$ dimensions to $n$ dimensions. Think going from $K$ D to $n$ D, so you have still some degrees of freedom. You need to put some restrictions on these dimensions, such that you can get a unique solution (in stead of every vector with random values for those free dimensions, those free dimensions need to be restricted).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where did you use the assumption that $D$ is full rank?

Comment: @Gigili So,as it is said, we are mapping a "bigger" space to a "smaller" space. $D$ is full rank implies that the entire "smaller" space is contained in the image which implies that a solution definitely exists. Therefore, it assures existence of a solution.

Comment: Got it, thanks again.

Comment: Sure, it's an adjective, referring to something cute and small. It also is a funny TV character.

Comment: Hope you got the intuition behind the arguments given here. Thanks.